# Complexity of Radix Sort

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, radix-sort

I am a little confused by the complexity proof of Radix Sort.

For **counting sort**, the complexity reported is $O(n+R)$, where $n$ is the number of items and $R$ is the range.

But this is not entirely correct, right? To do binary arithmetic on numbers as big as $R$, I need $\log_2 R$ operations for any deterministic hashing function. So the complexity of counting shot should be $O(\log_2 R \cdot (n+R))$.

Then the complexity of **radix sort** with base $b$ should be $O(\log_b R \cdot \log_2b \cdot (n+b))$, which is equivalent to $O(\log_2R \cdot n)$. For range $R = \Omega(n)$, this is $\Omega(n \log n)$ and thus not $O(n)$.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong in my proof? As far as I know, radix sort is $O(n)$ for $R = O(n^c)$.

Comment: You can use Mathjax here. See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was enabled on this stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We typically analyze algorithms in the so-called "RAM machine" or "transdichotomous model". In this model, operations on machine words take $O(1)$, and a machine word has length $O(\log n)$ bits, where $n$ is the size of the input (in bits), or any other polynomially related quantity.

If $R$ is polynomial in $n$ (in this case, the length of the array), then an integer in the range $\{1,\ldots,R\}$ can be stored in a single machine word, and so operations on such integers take constant time in this model.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your logic, we can use multiple machine words to represent $n$ using arbitrary precision arithmetic right? So $n$ should be unbounded for analyses.

Comment: Arbitrary precision arithmetic doesn't necessarily take $O(1)$, even in the transdichotomous model. The basic operations allowed by the model operate on machine words.

Comment: So it would be correct to say that radix sort is $O(n)$ for $R = O(n^c)$ iff $n < 2^{64}$ (assuming 64-bit word size)? I didn't see this discussed in typical radix sort complexity proofs so I am unsure if I am doing the proof right.

Comment: If $n < 2^{64}$ and $R = O(n^c)$ then radix sort is $O(1)$.

Comment: A machine word is defined in the transdichotomous model as a word of length $O(\log N)$ bits, where $N$ is the input size in bits.

Comment: True, I was abusing notation. In that case radix sort is indeed not $O(n)$, its $O(n\log n)$ for any finite word sized machine?

Comment: If the word size is fixed, then we're in the bit complexity model. It is less useful than the transdichotomous model to predict the behavior of actual algorithms.

Comment: Real-world machines can only access $O(1)$ memory, so any algorithm takes $O(1)$. This improves on your $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for! Just a followup. Are there any computational models that have finite word size but can access infinite memory? This encoding is certainly possible, you can always write the word size $w$ (for simplicity, multiple of 64 bits) for the rest of the input at the front of the input, then a special token. Then the rest of the input can be accessed as usual with this word size.

Comment: The bit complexity model only allows operations on bits. It is non-uniform, in the sense that it allows different algorithms for each input size (though you can ask them to be uniform). This model is popular for analyzing algorithms in arithmetic, for example integer multiplication algorithms, though some people (e.g. Fürer) say that the transdichotomous model is a better fit.